# Como coverto esta conexão e código com o DB para PDO com charset utf-8?

Tags: php, mysql

> Minha pergunta não estava clara, editei o título, parecia apenas sobre UTF-8, mas não é, é uma conversão de conexão e query para PDO
>   com UTF-8

```
<?php  
      //export.php  
 if(isset($_POST["export"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "simrede"); 

      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Cadastro_Alunos-Simrede.csv');  
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
      fputcsv($output, array('lastname', 'firstname', 'department', 'institution', 'username',  'email', 'city', 'course1', 'password'));  
      $query = "SELECT * from cs_alunos ORDER BY institution";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
      {
           fputcsv($output, $row);  
      }  
      fclose($output);  
 }  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conexão PDO é simples, para deixar ela como utf8 é só usar o código abaixo.

```
   <?php  
      //export.php  
 if(isset($_POST["export"]))  
 {  
    try {

        $host  = "localhost";
        $user  = "root";
        $pass  = "root";
        $dbname = "db";

        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);

        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Cadastro_Alunos-Simrede.csv');

        $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  

        fputcsv($output, array('lastname', 'firstname', 'department', 'institution', 'username',  'email', 'city', 'course1', 'password'));  

        $query = "SELECT * from cs_alunos ORDER BY institution";  

        $result = $con->query($query);  
        $alunos = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($alunos as $aluno)
        {
            fputcsv($output, $aluno["seu_campo_que_retorna_da_query"]);  
        }

        fclose($output); 

    }catch(PDOException $e){

        echo $e->getMessage();  
    } 
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Além da conexão, coloque o resto do código. `prepare()` `execute()` `fetchall()` . Acho que é isso que ele quer também.

Comment: @William a conexão PDO eu sei como é, o que quero saber é como fica o código restante, pois não basta mudar só a conexão.

Comment: @MiguelSilva então não sei muito bem o que você está pretendendo fazer com esse código, mas ai está o restante dele editado na resposta. ( PS: Se você estiver querendo converter esses registro em uma planilha excel sugiro usar alguma lib  como o ***PhpSpreadsheet***.)

Comment: @William esse código exporta uma tabela do DB em formato CSV, não entendi o que colocar em `"seu_campo_que_retorna_da_query"`

Comment: O Código está funcionando bem, gostaria apenas de atualizar para uma versão atualizada da conexão e consequentemente do restante do código